# Adding components to JFrame from next class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've got a problem. I have main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HomePanel game = new HomePanel();
    game.setVisible(true);
    game.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Home Panel with game:

```
  public HomePanel() {

    setSize(1280, 720);
    setLayout(null);
    setTitle("MILLION");

    bNewGame = new JButton("New Game");
    bNewGame.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    bNewGame.setBounds(550, 420, 180, 50);
    bNewGame.setToolTipText("Start a new adventure!");
    bNewGame.addActionListener(this);
```

with action listener:

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
    source = action.getSource();

    if (source == bNewGame) {
        new Test().setVisible(true);
```

and a lot of others. When I'm launching this window, after clicking on "New Game" i want to open components - I mean adding buttons and action listener of Test class, but i want to do it still in the same window, without opening a new one(it actually happens).

```
public class Test extends JFrame{
private JButton bCredits;

public Test() {
    setSize(1280, 720);
    setLayout(null);
    setTitle("TEST_TEST");

    bCredits = new JButton("Credits");
    bCredits.setBounds(550, 540, 180, 50);
    add(bCredits);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You probably want to replace the panel in the existing frame ... however it is not exactly clear. Would make sense you could provide a minimal running example to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my suggestion is use a `JFrame` called `GameFrame` or something. then add the `HomePanel` in the `gameFrame`.  make sure the `homePanel` extend `JPanel` or some container. when you want, just remove the `homePanel` from the frame and add the another view. something like

```
remove(homePanel);
add(nextView);
```

also make sure the `nextView` extends the `JPanel` or some container.
use a layout manger for better positioning